# PHP | array multisort can't make it work

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have multidimentional array which i want to sort by both employeeID's and Dates also.

i have tried multisort, but due to lack of knowedge and experience in mulisort array can't use it properly..

Here is the Array

```
Array
(
    [1::2014-02-01] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 15:44:16
            [InDate] => 2014-02-01
            [OutTime] => 17:36:19
            [OutDate] => 2014-03-06
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 2
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [5::2014-02-05] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 5
            [InTime] => 16:26:49
            [InDate] => 2014-02-05
            [OutTime] => 11:08:46
            [OutDate] => 2014-10-23
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 2
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [8::2014-02-09] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 20:39:15
            [InDate] => 2014-02-09
            [OutTime] => 02:56:07
            [OutDate] => 2015-02-17
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 2
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [6::2014-02-22] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 6
            [InTime] => 08:25:34
            [InDate] => 2014-02-22
            [OutTime] => 15:23:28
            [OutDate] => 2014-04-28
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 2
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [1::2014-04-11] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 06:50:13
            [InDate] => 2014-04-11
            [OutTime] => 05:11:56
            [OutDate] => 2014-05-24
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 4
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [9::2014-05-07] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 9
            [InTime] => 07:24:11
            [InDate] => 2014-05-07
            [OutTime] => 11:21:32
            [OutDate] => 2014-07-23
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 5
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [9::2014-05-17] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 9
            [InTime] => 21:45:48
            [InDate] => 2014-05-17
            [OutTime] => 09:33:54
            [OutDate] => 2015-02-27
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 5
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [11::2014-06-03] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 11
            [InTime] => 13:58:48
            [InDate] => 2014-06-03
            [OutTime] => 16:01:42
            [OutDate] => 2014-06-18
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 6
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [8::2014-07-21] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 15:40:51
            [InDate] => 2014-07-21
            [OutTime] => 03:54:36
            [OutDate] => 2014-07-14
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 7
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [9::2014-08-16] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 9
            [InTime] => 06:23:50
            [InDate] => 2014-08-16
            [OutTime] => 06:21:06
            [OutDate] => 2014-04-10
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 8
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [1::2014-09-23] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 06:19:24
            [InDate] => 2014-09-23
            [OutTime] => 23:10:20
            [OutDate] => 2015-09-26
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [3::2014-10-03] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 3
            [InTime] => 04:15:26
            [InDate] => 2014-10-03
            [OutTime] => 11:55:38
            [OutDate] => 2015-07-31
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 10
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [1::2014-10-19] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 09:43:12
            [InDate] => 2014-10-19
            [OutTime] => 02:51:56
            [OutDate] => 2015-05-03
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 10
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [8::2014-11-08] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 11:54:25
            [InDate] => 2014-11-08
            [OutTime] => 06:55:01
            [OutDate] => 2014-12-25
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 11
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [1::2014-11-28] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 20:25:13
            [InDate] => 2014-11-28
            [OutTime] => 21:46:02
            [OutDate] => 2015-07-31
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 11
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [8::2015-01-30] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 01:19:49
            [InDate] => 2015-01-30
            [OutTime] => 09:20:37
            [OutDate] => 2014-06-03
            [YearID] => 17
            [MonthID] => 1
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [11::2015-02-17] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 11
            [InTime] => 03:59:12
            [InDate] => 2015-02-17
            [OutTime] => 01:49:12
            [OutDate] => 2015-06-05
            [YearID] => 17
            [MonthID] => 2
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [6::2015-02-27] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 6
            [InTime] => 06:45:15
            [InDate] => 2015-02-27
            [OutTime] => 22:49:19
            [OutDate] => 2014-04-17
            [YearID] => 17
            [MonthID] => 2
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [3::2015-05-18] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 3
            [InTime] => 10:55:10
            [InDate] => 2015-05-18
            [OutTime] => 18:59:54
            [OutDate] => 2015-04-02
            [YearID] => 17
            [MonthID] => 5
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [5::2015-09-16] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 5
            [InTime] => 19:46:53
            [InDate] => 2015-09-16
            [OutTime] => 07:52:40
            [OutDate] => 2014-04-08
            [YearID] => 17
            [MonthID] => 9
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [11::2015-10-16] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 11
            [InTime] => 01:03:57
            [InDate] => 2015-10-16
            [OutTime] => 20:52:36
            [OutDate] => 2014-11-25
            [YearID] => 17
            [MonthID] => 10
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [6::2015-12-29] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 6
            [InTime] => 04:29:13
            [InDate] => 2015-12-29
            [OutTime] => 21:02:34
            [OutDate] => 2014-05-10
            [YearID] => 17
            [MonthID] => 12
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
        )

    [1::2014-09-20] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-20
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [1::2014-09-21] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-21
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [1::2014-09-22] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-22
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [1::2014-09-24] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-24
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [1::2014-09-25] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-25
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [1::2014-09-26] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 1
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-26
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [5::2014-09-20] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 5
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-20
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [5::2014-09-21] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 5
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-21
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [5::2014-09-22] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 5
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-22
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [5::2014-09-23] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 5
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-23
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [5::2014-09-24] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 5
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-24
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [5::2014-09-25] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 5
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-25
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [5::2014-09-26] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 5
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-26
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [8::2014-09-20] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-20
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [8::2014-09-21] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-21
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [8::2014-09-22] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-22
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [8::2014-09-23] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-23
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [8::2014-09-24] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-24
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [8::2014-09-25] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-25
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [8::2014-09-26] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 8
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-26
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [6::2014-09-20] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 6
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-20
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [6::2014-09-21] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 6
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-21
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [6::2014-09-22] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 6
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-22
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [6::2014-09-23] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 6
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-23
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [6::2014-09-24] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 6
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-24
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [6::2014-09-25] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 6
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-25
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [6::2014-09-26] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 6
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-26
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [9::2014-09-20] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 9
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-20
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [9::2014-09-21] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 9
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-21
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [9::2014-09-22] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 9
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-22
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [9::2014-09-23] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 9
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-23
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [9::2014-09-24] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 9
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-24
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [9::2014-09-25] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 9
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-25
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [9::2014-09-26] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 9
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-26
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [11::2014-09-20] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 11
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-20
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [11::2014-09-21] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 11
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-21
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [11::2014-09-22] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 11
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-22
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [11::2014-09-23] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 11
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-23
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [11::2014-09-24] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 11
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-24
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [11::2014-09-25] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 11
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-25
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [11::2014-09-26] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 11
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-26
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [3::2014-09-20] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 3
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-20
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [3::2014-09-21] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 3
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-21
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [3::2014-09-22] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 3
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-22
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [3::2014-09-23] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 3
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-23
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [3::2014-09-24] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 3
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-24
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [3::2014-09-25] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 3
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-25
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

    [3::2014-09-26] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeID] => 3
            [InTime] => 00:00:00
            [InDate] => 2014-09-26
            [OutTime] => 00:00:00
            [OutDate] => 0000-00-00
            [AttendanceStatus] => 2
            [YearID] => 16
            [MonthID] => 9
        )

)
```

Here There Are Two Keys EmployeeID and InDate inside inner arrays if you see.

I want to sort this array using both columns.. How can i make it possible??

-=-=-=-=-=--=--=

I tried PHP function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php
But couldn't Figure Out How to work with it..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php) or [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.uasort.php) . It expects the array and a callback which sorts 2 elements. It has to return an integer greater/equal/lower zero to map the first element as greater/equal/lower than the second element.

```
$arr = ...; // your array

// the callback has to return integer greater/equal/lower zero
uasort($arr, function($e1, $e2){

    return $el1['EmployeeID'] != $el2['EmployeeID'] ? // not equal
        $el1['EmployeeID'] - $el2['EmployeeID'] :  // return the difference (which maps to greater or lower)
        strtotime($el1['InDate']) - strtotime($el2['InDate']) // When both IDs equal use InDate for sorting

});
```

Comment: @SizzlingCode: If this solves your problem please accept the answer or provide more details